# Why are [regex] match() and -match different?

Tags: .net, powershell

I was playing around with regex in PowerShell when I stumbled across a strange scenario differing Powershell's `[regex]` class match with `-match`. In the case that I was attempting to remove empty lines from a string, when using `-replace` none of my expressions worked while with `[regex]` `replace()` removed the lines perfectly fine.

```bsh
PS C:\Users\Neko> $a = @"
line1

line2
line3

line4
"@
PS C:\Users\Neko> $a -match '\n^\s*$'
false
PS C:\Users\Neko> $b = [regex]::new('\n^\s*$',"IgnoreCase, Multiline")
PS C:\Users\Neko> $b.Matches($a)


Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 5
Length   : 1
Value    :


Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 18
Length   : 1
Value    :
```

I haven't seen this in any other case that I've tested yet but I have no idea what the differences between the two could be or what is causing these differed results. This is the same with `-replace` (which makes sense) but I have no idea what may be causing this.

---

So what are the differences between the PowerShell `-match` and `-replace` methods to the .NET regular expression class `match()` and `replace()` methods and why are they different?

Comment: the PoSh operators use a _simplified for admin use_ version of the usual regex dotnet method. for instance, by default the PoSh operators are NOT case sensitive ... but the dotnet method is.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey What modification for simplicity of this method in PowerShell could warrant two different results of a regular expression? Is this a bug in PowerShell or is this intended? When should I use `-match` and vice versa?

Comment: hi, you could specify multiline mode as an inline option `$a -match '(?m)\n^\s*$'` (note the `(?m)` at the beginning.

Comment: @IronMan This works too. Thanks

Comment: @NekoMusume - now that have re-read your code [*blush*], your two regex calls don't use the same modifiers. you would get different results from the dotnet stuff if you used two different pattern/modifier combos. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is probably `Multiline`

```
$regex = [regex]'\n^\s*$'
$regexM = [regex]::new('\n^\s*$',"IgnoreCase, Multiline")
$a = @"
line1

line2
line3

line4
"@
$a -match $regex
false
$a -match $regexM
true
```

Also note that actually creating the regex is computationally expensive while running it is not.  I recommend assigning all the regex [together](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-11-06-powershell-hashtable-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about/) at the beginning so you only compile them once.  It also makes the actual matching more readable (if you pick good names):

```
$regex = @{
    ExtraWhitespace = [regex]::new('\n^\s*$',"IgnoreCase, Multiline")
}
$a -match $regex.ExtraWhitespace
```

Comment: Wow I didn't consider this because `^.` and `.$` returned true. Thank you

Comment: It's one string, hence the reason your 'Multiline' regex works   $a.Count [The property 'Count' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.], you have to make it an array [-split "`n"], then do [| ForEach {$PSItem -match '^\s*$'}].

Comment: Makes sense.  Here's what I typically use to break the multiline strings into an array: ```$a = @"<multiline text>"@ -replace "`r","" -split "`n"```  the replace allows it to work on both Windows and Linux without leaving CR at the end of each line

Comment: Yeppers. As the old adage goes, "if you have a code problem, and then require regex, you now have two problems".  ;-}

Comment: You can also use `-split '\r?\n'` to match both CRLF and LF-only newlines.