# How can I write a regular expression to match a multiline pattern?

Tags: regex, powershell, sftp

I am trying to parse a SFTP config file (sshd_config.txt) using PowerShell to get all existing SFTP profiles. The below text is just 3 profiles, but there may be hundreds I would need to parse.  Once I have a working regex to output all matches to a PowerShell object, I should have no problem parsing the individual profiles.  I just can't figure out how to write the Regex. I did try using other examples, but I couldn't separate each into individual matches.

I need to match the start "^Match" and all lines until a blank line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Match User thedomain\user1
    ChrootDirectory E:\sftp\heatism\user1
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match User thedomain\user2
    ChrootDirectory E:\sftp\heatism\user2
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match User thedomain\user3
    ChrootDirectory E:\sftp\heatism\user3
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are \[regex\] match() and -match different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64883558/why-are-regex-match-and-match-different)

Answer (score 3):

To match across multiple lines:

- You need a single, multi-line string as input, which is what [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Raw` switch provides (by default, `Get-Content` outputs the input file's lines *one by one*).
- Additionally, your [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) must use the following [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options):

  - `Multiline` (`m`), in order to make `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of *individual lines* inside a multi-line string; `\A` and `\Z` (or `\z`, to match only the very end of a string, even if it is a newline) can then be used to match the overall beginning and end of the multi-line string.
  - `Singleline` (`s`) if you want `.` to also match *newline* characters (`\n`).
  - The simplest way to specify these options is inside `(?...)` at the start of the regex; in the case at hand: `(?ms)`

To put it all together, using a modified version of [Jan's helpful regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67940707/45375) and the .NET [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) method for finding *all* matches for a given regex (note that PowerShell's [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) only ever looks for the *first*):

```
foreach ($m in [regex]::Matches(
  (Get-Content -Raw sshd_config.txt), 
  '(?ms)^Match User .+?(?=^$|\Z)'
)) {
  # Split the block of line into the first and the remaining lines.  
  $first, $rest = $m.Value.Trim() -split '\r?\n'
  # Create an aux. (ordered) hashtable and fill it with the user name
  # extracted from the first line.
  $oht = [ordered] @{ UserName = (-split $first)[-1] }
  # Loop over the remaining lines, split them into name and value,
  # and add them to the hashtable.
  foreach ($line in $rest) {
    $name, $value = $line.Trim() -split ' ', 2
    $oht[$name] = $value
  }
  # Convert the hashtable to a custom object and output it.
  [pscustomobject] $oht
}
```

With your sample input, you'll see the following output, representing the default formatting of the `[pscustomobject]` instances that were created:

```
UserName             : thedomain\user1
ChrootDirectory      : E:\sftp\heatism\user1
PermitTunnel         : no
AllowAgentForwarding : no
AllowTcpForwarding   : no
X11Forwarding        : no
ForceCommand         : internal-sftp

UserName             : thedomain\user2
ChrootDirectory      : E:\sftp\heatism\user2
PermitTunnel         : no
AllowAgentForwarding : no
AllowTcpForwarding   : no
X11Forwarding        : no
ForceCommand         : internal-sftp

UserName             : thedomain\user3
ChrootDirectory      : E:\sftp\heatism\user3
PermitTunnel         : no
AllowAgentForwarding : no
AllowTcpForwarding   : no
X11Forwarding        : no
ForceCommand         : internal-sftp
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use (thanks to [**@mklement0**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for some improvements):

```
(?m)^Match[\s\S]+?(?=^$|\Z)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dnquk3/1/) and mind the `multiline` flag.

---

Explanation:

```
^Match    # match "Match" at the very beginning of a line
[\s\S]*?  # match anything else lazily
(?=^$|\Z) # make sure what follows is a blank line or the very end of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to start the pattern with `Match` followed by the rest of the line. Then continue matching all non empty lines using a negative lookahead.

```
^Match .*(?:\r?\n(?!$).*)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^Match`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!$)` Match a newline and assert that the line is not empty
  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z4luah/1).

If you also don't want to match a line that contains only spaces:

```
^Match .*(?:\r?\n(?![\p{Zs}\t]*$).*)*
```

Example

```
$allText = Get-Content -Raw sshd_config.txt
$pattern = "(?m)^Match .*(?:\r?\n(?![\p{Zs}\t]*$).*)*"
Select-String $pattern -input $allText -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Value 
    "--------------------------"
}
```

Output

```
Match User thedomain\user1
    ChrootDirectory E:\sftp\heatism\user1
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
--------------------------
Match User thedomain\user2
    ChrootDirectory E:\sftp\heatism\user2
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
--------------------------
Match User thedomain\user3
    ChrootDirectory E:\sftp\heatism\user3
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
--------------------------
```